# Xamarin Forms Listview group header not being updated on property changed

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Grouped ListView bound to `MyGroup` (see below) that contains some property but when that property is being changed the view is not getting updated although I call `OnPropertyChanged`

My Class

```
     public class MyGroup : ObservableCollection<Items>, INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
         private string foo;
         public string Foo 
         {
             get => foo;
             set 
               {
                  foo = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Foo));
               }
          }
         ...
     }
```

My View

```
  <ListView ItemSource="{Binding GroupList}">
     <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#2196F3"
                             Padding="5,5,5,5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Header}" Grid.Column="1" FontAttributes="Italic" TextColor="White"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Foo}" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
       </ListView>
```

MyViewModel

```
   public List<MyGroup>  GroupList { get => groupList ;set => SetProperty(ref groupList, value); }
```

Comment: Show some more code. Your source needs to implement IGrouping so it is not clear how this works at all, what is your source what is your grouping key etc. Also most of people have no idea what is ObservableRangeCollection as it is not a standard control.

Comment: @IvanIčin I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you bind Foo in ListView Group header, you said that group header don't update when property changed, but I don't see where do you change this property. I've written a sample - I changed the first item group header when button click.

```
 public class PersonList1 : ObservableCollection<Person1>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _heading;
    public string Heading
    {
        get { return _heading; }
        set
        {
            _heading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Heading");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Person1> Persons => this;

    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
public class Person1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
        }
    }
}

<StackLayout>
        <ListView IsGroupingEnabled="true" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPeople}">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="change header" />
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page15 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonList1> ListOfPeople { get; set; }
   

    public Page15 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        var sList = new PersonList1()
{
    new Person1() { FirstName = "Sally", LastName = "Sampson" },
    new Person1() { FirstName = "Taylor", LastName = "Swift" },
    new Person1() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" }
};
        sList.Heading = "S";

        var dList = new PersonList1()
{
    new Person1() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" }
};
        dList.Heading = "D";

        var jList = new PersonList1()
{
    new Person1() { FirstName = "Billy", LastName = "Joel" }
};
        jList.Heading = "J";

        ListOfPeople = new ObservableCollection<PersonList1>()
{
    sList,
    dList,
    jList
};

        this.BindingContext = this;

    }

    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListOfPeople[0].Heading = "this is test";
    }
}
```

You can see the the first ListView group header property change as "this is test".

Comment: i see my problem my `PropertyChangedEventHandler` stays null

Comment: @Joe B,According to your code and description, I can not reproduce your issue, so can you provide one simple sample that can reproduce your issue at github, I will try to download and reproduce your issue at my side.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not complete enough. Please add detail of how you are calling/setting values to property.

BTW, instead of using this(a wild guess,as you have not provided enough info):

```
public List<MyGroup>  GroupList { get => groupList ;set => SetProperty(ref groupList, value); }
```

try this:

```
public List<MyGroup>  GroupList {
get{
     return groupList;
}
set{
     groupList = value;
     OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GroupList));
}
```